# Слишком медленный запрос с использованием LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация, запрос, like

Здравствуйте!
Имеется таблица, около 700К строк (тестовая), боевая около 10М строк. При поиске по таблице (пример запроса):

```
SELECT `p`.*, (SELECT name FROM brands b WHERE b.id = p.brand_id) brand_name, (SELECT name FROM dealers d WHERE d.id = p.dealer_id) dealer_name
FROM `parts` `p`
WHERE (`p`.`part_number` LIKE "%123" OR `p`.`part_new` LIKE "%123" OR `p`.`part_old` LIKE "%123" OR `p`.`part_alt` LIKE "%123")
ORDER BY `p`.`part_number` ASC
LIMIT 100
```

Запрос занимает около 56.0167 секунд, а иногда и 87.1817 секунд.

EXPLAIN: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Типы полей:

```
part_number | varchar(100)  | latin1_swedish_ci | NOT NULL
part_new    | varchar(100)  | latin1_swedish_ci | NOT NULL
part_old    | varchar(100)  | latin1_swedish_ci | NOT NULL
part_alt    | varchar(100)  | latin1_swedish_ci | NOT NULL
```

Пытался поставить индекс, но оно его не подхватывает, подхватывает другой совершенно:

```
ALTER TABLE  `parts` ADD UNIQUE  `search_by_partnum_cols` (`part_number`, `part_new`, `part_old`, `part_alt`, `dealer_id`, `brand_id`)
```

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как можно ускорить сей запрос. С индексами мало опыта и не могу найти толковую статью как их расставлять: пихать все из запроса, или только часть и т.п. ...

Comment: Сомнения терзают, что такой LIKE можно оптимизировать. Может сделать колонки с обратным порядком букв, тогда условие переписывается так `p.reverse_part_number LIKE '321%'`. Так точно появляется вероятность использования индекса по p.reverse_part_number, если он будет построен.

Comment: @Sergey заюзал USE INDEX, хоть и не люблю его. Время ответа сократилось до 4секунд. Правда я не понимаю, нормальная ли практика юзать USE INDEX ?

Comment: Не понял. было 88, стало 4 и ещё не довольны? Или до 4 секунд означает -4 секунды. 88 - 4 = 84?

Comment: @Sergey до 4х, правильно поняли)

Comment: Тогда дело не в LIKE, либо одно из двух...

Comment: @Sergey может дело в запросе на создание индекса? Я в индексах не селён, мог неправильно что-то поставить...

Comment: @Sergey может подскажите толковую статью / книгу по расстановке индексов?

Comment: Он с таким запросом в любом случае не может эффективно использовать индексы. Во первых % в начале строки делает это невозможным, во вторых у вас OR по 4м полям, т.е. если он даже может пойти по неким индексам ему придется идти по отдельным индексам по каждому из 4х полей и объединять результаты (если он вообще до такого додумается). Либо полным перебором таблицы. Но ваш план выполнения говорит о том, что он каким то странным образом идет по инжексу, причем только по одному из 4х полей, что скорее всего медленнее чем просто перебор таблицы

Comment: И плюс к этому подзапросы получающие имена лучше выполнить как join

Comment: @Mike "И плюс к этому подзапросы получающие имена лучше выполнить как join" – уверены? Раньше там джоины стояли с страница запрос длился около 10 секунд. Сколько сейчас запрос длится? 0.3 - 0.5 секунды :)

Comment: @Mike эффективно или нет, но запрос ускорился с помощью принудительного юзания индекса ...